# RecyclerView Grid Layout Fit items to screen

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I want to fit the items to the screen. When I have 4 four item I used this:

```
 recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```

And when I have 20 item I used this code snippet:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 3, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```

What I want to do is I want to fit all the items to the screen.

[image]

Comment: any solution for this problem?